# Read values from a complex XML using java

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to read a XML file using JAVA .
XML file:-<

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<document>
 <testCaseDataName>
  <id>1</id >
  <testCaseName>EditTest</testCaseName >
  <expectedResult>true</expectedResult >

 </testCaseDataName>
 <testCaseDataName>
  <id>2</id >
  <testCaseName>AddTest</testCaseName >
  <expectedResult>true</expectedResult>
  <parameter>
    <key>featues</key >
    <value>new</value>
    </parameter>
 </testCaseDataName>

  <testCaseDataName>
  <id>3</id >
  <testCaseName>AddTest</testCaseName >
  <expectedResult>true</expectedResult>
  <parameter>
    <key>projectType</key >
    <value>old</value>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
    <key>Name</key >
    <value>Marvel</value>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
    <key>status</key >
    <value>ACTIVE</value>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
    <key>canOrder</key >
    <value>Yes</value>
    </parameter>
 </testCaseDataName>
 <testCaseDataName>
  <id>4</id >
  <testCaseName>AddTest</testCaseName >
  <expectedResult>empty</expectedResult>
  <parameter>
    <key>projectType</key >
    <value>GEN</value>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
    <key>Name</key >
    <value>HPM</value>
    </parameter>
    <key>no status</key >
    <value>ACTIVE</value>
    <parameter>
    <key>canOrder</key >
    <value>Yes</value>
    </parameter>
 </testCaseDataName>

 </document>
```

I am trying to read the key and value from parameters to a hashmap .here is my code:-

```
public class JDOM {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File xsdfile = new File("file.xsd");
        XMLReaderJDOMFactory schemafac = new XMLReaderXSDFactory(xsdfile);
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(schemafac);
        //Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(new File("testdbcsv/ACL.xml"));
        Document doc = builder.build(new File("file.xml"));
        Element root = doc.getRootElement();
        for (Element testcase : root.getChildren()) {
            String id = testcase.getChildText("id");
            String testCaseName = testcase.getChildText("testCaseName");
            String expectedResult = testcase.getChildText("expectedResult");
            System.out.println(expectedResult);
            HashMap<String,String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
            Element params = testcase.getChild("parameter");
            System.out.println(params);
            if (params != null ) {
                Iterator<Element> it = params.getChildren().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Element key = it.next();
                    Element val = it.next();
                    parameters.put(key.getValue(), val.getValue());
                }
            }
            parameters.put("expectedResult", expectedResult);
            ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
            String jsonString = obj.writeValueAsString(parameters);
            System.out.println(jsonString);

         }
        }
    }
```

My code is only reading the first set of key and value and not reading the other keys and values.
The output is :-

```
{"expectedResult":"true"}
{"featues":"w,f","expectedResult":"true"}
{"projectType":"MEMOGEN","expectedResult":"true"}
{"projectType":"MEMOGEN","expectedResult":"empty"}
```

I want the other key value also to be in the string. Can anyone please help and fix my code

Comment: could anyone answer this? 
urgently needed
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757825/how-to-read-xml-attribute-values-hierarchically-like-parentnodename-childnodeatt][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757825/how-to-read-xml-attribute-values-hierarchically-like-parentnodename-childnodeatt

Comment: look at my answer below . It should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Element> params = testcase.getChildren("parameter");
            for(Element ele : params){
                String key = ele.getChildText("key");
                String value = ele.getChildText("value");
                parameters.put(key, value);
            }
```

I think this will solve my problem .

Answer (score 1):

You're using

```
testcase.getChild("parameter")
```

`getChild()` returns the **first** child element with the given name. You want all the children named "parameter". So you need to call

```
testcase.getChildren("parameter")
```

and iterate through all the returned elements.

Comment: It returns a list of parameter children and I should iterate over it right?

Comment: Yes. Read the javadoc: http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#getChildren%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath  This will help you to read many complex expressions from a xml.

Write a xslt which will take your xml as input and render your json. Xslt supports for, if loops as well. This is  time efficient as well. I have parsed an xml of size 3 MB in 100 ms (I performed hundreds of operations inside xslt)

Comment: I just want to continue it using JDOM only . Can you please help me on how to read the other parameters please.

Comment: When you've already said you are new to this, and someone makes a helpful suggestion to adopt a different approach, then it's polite to say why you don't think that approach meets your requirements.